# Web browser that can not be closed

Tags: vb.net, locked

I am trying to create a locked down browser for the employees at my work to use at a kiosk. I need to prevent the user from getting out of the app. I have figured out how to prevent them from closing it by pressing alt-f4 or ctrl-f4 but I would like to also prevent alt-esc, ctrl-esc, alt-tab, and the windows key. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? I am new to windows application development but have experience in web vb.net. I am using VB.NET 2010 express. Thanks.

Comment: Can you just disable the keys?

Comment: I would like not to disable ctrl, alt, or tab but I do not think that the users will need esc or the windows key.

Comment: This is a job for group policy settings, not code. Ask questions about that on [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=kiosk+a

Comment: Don't forget about combinations like ctrl+shift+esc

Comment: Thanks I forgot about that one.

Comment: I am trying to keep the group policy editing to a minimum. We are going to use it to disable everything but logout when ctrl-alt-del is pressed and that is only kept so we have a way to get to an admin account. Do you know off hand what GP would prevent these other key strokes?

Comment: As @cody said - Group Policy is the way to go on this because the user could just run task manager and close your applications process from there.

Comment: Why would you try to keep group policy editing to a minimum? That's a way better option than trying to write code to handle every case. I can think of tons more ways to get out of your application, other than the ones you (and other commenters) have already listed. This is broken security, all you're doing is locking down users that don't know the workaround.

Comment: The reason for keeping it to a minimum is gp editing will have to be done on a machine by machine bases because this is a small network with no AD server. So I want our default image to be edited as little as possible so that the techs can just install the app and be done.

Comment: I'm not going for a completely locked down app but merely one that prevents the average user from exiting. A pad lock will do in this case I don't need fort knox.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do that, why not just Cancel the close?

Handle the `Closing` event on your form and set Cancel to true.

```
Public Class MyForm Inherits Form
    //Wire the event...
    Public Sub MyForm_FormClosing(sender as Object, args as FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Closing
        args.Cancel = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

That way, you can decide when it should be closed and it doesn't matter what other ways the user thinks of.

As Cody mentioned in the comments, a lot of this should be enforced (and some can only be enforced) by Group Policy. You can script Group Policy settings, to make it easily deployable.

Comment: That is how I have handled the disabling of closing but I also don't want them to be able to open another application or switch applications.

Comment: This method won't work if the user ends the applications' process using task manager

Comment: Yes this was exactly my point, there is no **code only** solution - as noted by @Cody in the comments to the original question

Comment: @Matt, ah - that comment discussion was going on while I was writing my answer. I agree.